# Google Fit API Sign in Required

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-api-client, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am working on a google fit app that will connect to a bluetooth sensor and read heart rate. I followed google's basic sensor demo on GitHub, but Im stuck on the sign in for google fit. Here is the code:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingDeque;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.Fitness;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.BleDevice;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataPoint;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataSource;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataType;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Field;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Value;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.BleScanCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.DataSourcesRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.OnDataPointListener;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.SensorRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.StartBleScanRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.result.DataSourcesResult;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = "GoogleFitSensorCode";
    // [START auth_variable_references]
    private GoogleApiClient mClient = null;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 34;

    // [START mListener_variable_reference]
    // Need to hold a reference to this listener, as it's passed into the "unregister"
    // method in order to stop all sensors from sending data to this listener.
    private OnDataPointListener mListener;
// [END mListener_variable_reference]


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Now we want to check if persmissions are given to the app
        // When permissions are revoked the app is restarted so onCreate is sufficient to check for
        // permissions core to the Activity's functionality.
        if (!checkPermissions()) {
            requestPermissions();
        }

        if (!checkPermissionsBody()) {
            requestPermissionsBody();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // This ensures that if the user denies the permissions then uses Settings to re-enable
        // them, the app will start working.
        buildFitnessClient();


        BleScanCallback callback = new BleScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onDeviceFound(BleDevice device) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Found bluetooth Device");
                // A device that provides the requested data types is available
                PendingResult<Status> pendingResult =
                        Fitness.BleApi.claimBleDevice(mClient, device);
                Log.d(TAG,"Claimed bluetooth Device");
            }
            @Override
            public void onScanStopped() {
                // The scan timed out or was interrupted
            }

        };


        StartBleScanRequest request = new StartBleScanRequest.Builder()
                .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
                .setBleScanCallback(callback)
                .build();

        if (mClient != null){
            PendingResult<Status> pendingResult =
                    Fitness.BleApi.startBleScan(mClient, request);
            Log.d(TAG,"Find Sources");

            // Connect to the Client
            mClient.connect();

            // Search for the data sources
            findFitnessDataSources();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG,"API client is null");
        }

    }

    // Now we need a function to check permissions
    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        int permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    // Now we need a function to check permissions body sensors
    private boolean checkPermissionsBody() {
        int permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS);
        return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }


    // If permissions are not given, we need to request permissions
    private void requestPermissions() {
        Log.d(TAG,"getting permissions");
        boolean shouldProvideRationale =
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        Log.d(TAG,String.valueOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION));
        // Provide an additional rationale to the user. This would happen if the user denied the
        // request previously, but didn't check the "Don't ask again" checkbox.
        if (shouldProvideRationale) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");
            Snackbar.make(
                    findViewById(R.id.activity_main),
                    R.string.permission_rationale,
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // Request permission
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permission");
            // Request permission. It's possible this can be auto answered if device policy
            // sets the permission in a given state or the user denied the permission
            // previously and checked "Never ask again".
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    // If permissions are not given, we need to request permissions
    private void requestPermissionsBody() {
        Log.d(TAG,"getting permissions");
        boolean shouldProvideRationale =
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS);
        Log.d(TAG,String.valueOf(Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS));
        // Provide an additional rationale to the user. This would happen if the user denied the
        // request previously, but didn't check the "Don't ask again" checkbox.
        if (shouldProvideRationale) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");
            Snackbar.make(
                    findViewById(R.id.activity_main),
                    R.string.permission_rationale,
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // Request permission
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS},
                                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permission");
            // Request permission. It's possible this can be auto answered if device policy
            // sets the permission in a given state or the user denied the permission
            // previously and checked "Never ask again".
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    // Now we need to build the API client
    // [START auth_build_googleapiclient_beginning]
    /**
     *  Build a {@link GoogleApiClient} that will authenticate the user and allow the application
     *  to connect to Fitness APIs. The scopes included should match the scopes your app needs
     *  (see documentation for details). Authentication will occasionally fail intentionally,
     *  and in those cases, there will be a known resolution, which the OnConnectionFailedListener()
     *  can address. Examples of this include the user never having signed in before, or having
     *  multiple accounts on the device and needing to specify which account to use, etc.
     */
    private void buildFitnessClient() {
        if (mClient == null && checkPermissions() && checkPermissionsBody()) {

            GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ))
                    .build();

            mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ))
                    .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
                    .addApi(Fitness.BLE_API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(
                            new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                                @Override
                                public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Connected!!!");
                                    // Now you can make calls to the Fitness APIs.
                                    //findFitnessDataSources();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                                    // If your connection to the sensor gets lost at some point,
                                    // you'll be able to determine the reason and react to it here.
                                    if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                        Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
                                    } else if (i
                                            == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                        Log.i(TAG,
                                                "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    )
                    .enableAutoManage(this, 0, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Google Play services connection failed. Cause: " +
                                    result.toString());
                            Snackbar.make(
                                    MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.activity_main),
                                    "Exception while connecting to Google Play services: " +
                                            result.getErrorMessage(),
                                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .build();
        }
    }
// [END auth_build_googleapiclient_beginning]

    /**
     * Find available data sources and attempt to register on a specific {@link DataType}.
     * If the application cares about a data type but doesn't care about the source of the data,
     * this can be skipped entirely, instead calling
     *     {@link com.google.android.gms.fitness.SensorsApi
     *     #register(GoogleApiClient, SensorRequest, DataSourceListener)},
     * where the {@link SensorRequest} contains the desired data type.
     */
    private void findFitnessDataSources() {
        // [START find_data_sources]
        // Note: Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources() requires the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
        Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(mClient, new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
                // At least one datatype must be specified.
                .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
                // Can specify whether data type is raw or derived.
                //.setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
                .build())
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Result: " + dataSourcesResult.getStatus().toString());

                        for (DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources()) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Data source found: " + dataSource.toString());
                            Log.i(TAG, "Data Source type: " + dataSource.getDataType().getName());

                            //Let's register a listener to receive Activity data!
                            if (dataSource.getDataType().equals(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE)
                                    && mListener == null) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Data source for LOCATION_SAMPLE found!  Registering.");
                                registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource,
                                        DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
        // [END find_data_sources]
    }

    /**
     * Register a listener with the Sensors API for the provided {@link DataSource} and
     * {@link DataType} combo.
     */
    private void registerFitnessDataListener(DataSource dataSource, DataType dataType) {
        // [START register_data_listener]
        mListener = new OnDataPointListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
                for (Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                    Value val = dataPoint.getValue(field);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Detected DataPoint field: " + field.getName());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Detected DataPoint value: " + val);
                }
            }
        };

        Fitness.SensorsApi.add(
                mClient,
                new SensorRequest.Builder()
                        .setDataSource(dataSource) // Optional but recommended for custom data sets.
                        .setDataType(dataType) // Can't be omitted.
                        .setSamplingRate(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build(),
                mListener)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        if (status.isSuccess()) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Listener registered!");
                        } else {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Listener not registered.");
                        }
                    }
                });
        // [END register_data_listener]
    }

    /**
     * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult");
        Log.i(TAG,String.valueOf(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED));
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
                // If user interaction was interrupted, the permission request is cancelled and you
                // receive empty arrays.
                Log.i(TAG, "User interaction was cancelled.");
            } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission was granted.
                buildFitnessClient();
            } else {
                // Permission denied.

                // In this Activity we've chosen to notify the user that they
                // have rejected a core permission for the app since it makes the Activity useless.
                // We're communicating this message in a Snackbar since this is a sample app, but
                // core permissions would typically be best requested during a welcome-screen flow.

                // Additionally, it is important to remember that a permission might have been
                // rejected without asking the user for permission (device policy or "Never ask
                // again" prompts). Therefore, a user interface affordance is typically implemented
                // when permissions are denied. Otherwise, your app could appear unresponsive to
                // touches or interactions which have required permissions.
                Snackbar.make(
                        findViewById(R.id.activity_main),
                        R.string.permission_denied_explanation,
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                        .setAction(R.string.settings, new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                // Build intent that displays the App settings screen.
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(
                                        Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",
                                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

===============Edit: Adding the output =================
This code creates the app on the emulator, then asks for body permissions and location permissions. When it tries to connect the googleapiclient it has the following output:

```
I/GoogleFitSensorCode: Connected!!!
I/GoogleFitSensorCode: Result: Status{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{7a2c07b: android.os.BinderProxy@1139e98}}
```

Ive been trying to get around this problem now for 2 days, any suggestions?

Comment: @Ifor, I added the output. So as you can see the api client fires the onConnected() method. However, when I call the findFitnessDataSources() in onResume(), it says that a sign-in is needed.

Comment: If i remove google sign in options:
 GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ))
                    .build();

Then I am prompted to sign into my google account which leads me Connection cancelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these lines above:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ))
                    .build();
```

This will display a dialog to sign into google.

Create a google developer account and assign the authentication credentials. Its possible that your personal security credentials could interfere with authentication otherwise.